# Certain characters are replaced with others when writing to a file?

Tags: java, server, file-transfer

I have got a c# program which sends a .zip file over a network socket. My java server listens to the port and directly writes to a new file but some of the characters are replaced with question mark(?).

This for example is just a single line from the .zip file I am trying to transfer:

¬ ßÂÔìÑ· ‹åÔ>ßÂÔÅ]        tÅ™nÙ–-É’-Ë>ãñ}a[6ØžÍè$yÆYH>Z3-©qÏôÐ3cKÄqŒI°Ù°Ï·°`KX²,K6\

And this is what the java server writes to the file(I've put the question mark in brackets):

¬ ßÂÔìÑ· ‹åÔ>ßÂÔÅ]        tÅ™nÙ–-É’-Ë>ãñ}a[6ØžÍè$yÆYH>Z3-©qÏôÐ3cKÄqŒI°Ù°Ï(?)·°`KX²,K6\

So the character code of this particular case is 144 and it is replaced with 63 or the question mark sign.

I assume that the problem is somewhere in my java server.

```java
private String ReadMessage() {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        char recieved;
        try {

            recieved = (char)stream.read();
            if(recieved != '$') {

                do {

                    message.append(recieved);
                    recieved = (char)stream.read();
                }while(recieved!='$');
            }
            return message.toString();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    private void InitWriter(){
      projectwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("D:\\help\\" + this.participant) + ".zip"));
    }




    private void ProjectWrite(String valueOfMesseage) throws IOException{
        projectwriter.append(valueOfMesseage);  
    }
```

I use the $ sign as the end of the message.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're sending binary data, treat it as binary data. Not characters.

Comment: It's cause it is not a character Java understands.

Comment: Is the zip file corrupted? If it opens okay then there's almost certainly nothing wrong. If it's corrupted, then maybe either your server or client is treating something as text, not binary data.